# preventing JS running when the page is not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, loading

I have encountered a problem. When I use jQuery to load a page that contains heavy javascript, the page freezes. I believe it is because the js executes before the page loads as my local site does not freeze. However, $(document).ready(function(){}); seems not working with dynamically loaded pages? is that true? or anything i could do to solve this problem. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` works fine in dynamic pages. There must be an error in your code somewhere.

The first thing to do is to try View Source and save the HTML to a plain `.html` file, then load that file in your browser. If that still fails then you know the problem has nothing to do with the server-side ASP/PHP/whatever code. Then try removing HTML and JavaScript piece by piece until the problem disappears. That'll help you narrow down the culprit line(s). If you can reduce your page to a small file that still demonstrates the problem, post that here and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(window).load(function(){
dosomething();
});
```

It will run the js after the whole page is loaded.

Avoid using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
dosomething();
});
```

It will run the js just after the loading of DOM.